GitHub Search Authorization
I am trying to authorize my requests to the search feature within the GitHub API. I generated a classic token with all permissions unchecked (since I am only searching through public repos). This token however doesn't seem to work as I get a 'Bad Credentials' error.
I tried the following -

import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token < MY_TOKEN >',
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/rate_limit', headers=headers, proxies = custom_proxies)

print(response.content) 


I then get the following error-
b'{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest","status":"401"}'


Try Bearer instead of token. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/authenticating-to-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28

I gave it a shot but doesn't seem to work either.

The bad credentials error indicates that the token you're using is invalid or not recognized.
Can you please check your API token here https://github.com/settings/tokens

Ensure the token has at least public_repo permission.

Then I give you a code alternative:
import requests

token = '<MY_TOKEN>' # Write here your generated token

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'token {token}',
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/rate_limit', headers=headers)

print(response.content)

Regards!

I enabled the public_repo permissions and regenerated the token. Still running into the same issue. Are there any other permissions required? Thanks!

please check the following permissions: repo, repo:status, public_repo, repo:invite, security_events and delete_repo

All done. Still running into the same issue. I am working with GitHub enterprise here, does that make any difference to the process?

No, it doesn't make any difference i think

@SarthakBhargava I have followed all the steps correctlly but using powershell and i get an answer with my token, please check the permissions or regenerate a new token and it should work

Replace word token with Bearer. Here is the curl command that shows the expected headers:
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/rate_limit

